# I want ToC, LoF, LoT and bibligraphy to have default style while using fncychap

Tags: table-of-contents, fncychap

I'm using fncychap for having beautiful chapters style but the problem is the the chosen style is applied on ToC, LoF, LoT and bibligraphy which I want them to be in default style. Is there a way to make exceptions for fncychap package ?

Thanks

Comment: I doubt preventing that will be super easy without redefining some lower level commands, but it would help to know what document class you are using (and any other settings that might affect chapter headings, or the ToC, LoF and LoT). Post a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)?

Answer (score 2):

```tex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\FncychapCopyCmds[2]{%
  \csletcs{appendix#1}{appendix#2}%
  \csletcs{@makechapterhead#1} {@makechapterhead#2}%
  \csletcs{@schapter#1}        {@schapter#2}%
  \csletcs{@makeschapterhead#1}{@makeschapterhead#2}%
}

\newcommand\FncychapStyleOn {\FncychapCopyCmds{}{@fncy}}
\newcommand\FncychapStyleOff{\FncychapCopyCmds{}{@orig}}
\makeatother

\FncychapCopyCmds{@orig}{}
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
\FncychapCopyCmds{@fncy}{}

\begin{document}
\FncychapStyleOff % deactivate fncychap style
\tableofcontents

\FncychapStyleOn  % activate fncychap style
\chapter{title}
\chapter{title}

\appendix
\FncychapStyleOff % deactivate again
\chapter{title}
\end{document}
```

[image: toc]
[image: chapter 1]
[image: chapter 2]
[image: appendix A]

Comment: Wow, very elegant!